# How to fetch data and store into multiple files based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

test.csv

```
name,age,n1,n2,n3
a,21,1,2,3
b,22,4,9,0
c,25,4,5,6
d,25,41,5,6
e,25,4,66,6
f,25,4,5,66
g,25,4,55,6
h,25,4,5,56
i,25,41,5,61
j,25,4,51,60
k,20,40,50,60
l,21,40,51,60
```

My code till reading and storing  into dict

```
import pandas as pd

input_file = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
for i in range(0, len(input_file['name'])):   
    dict1 = {}
    dict1["name"] = str(input_file['name'][i])
    dict1["age"] = str(input_file['age'][i])
    dict1["n1"] = str(input_file['n1'][i])
    dict1["n2"] = str(input_file['n2'][i])
    dict1["n3"] = str(input_file['n3'][i])
```

I want to generate output in multiple file for each 5 rows of data (But this I need to do using writeline function in python as I need to do many stuff in writelines. FIle name should be generated dynamically also input will be dynamic (Meaning more rows can come)

example or expected output (herre file name must be dynamic)

```
out_file = open('File1.xml', 'w')
out_file.writelines(I will process with dictionary data row by row)
out_file.writelines("\n")
```

File1

```
a,21,1,2,3
b,22,4,9,0
c,25,4,5,6
d,25,41,5,6
e,25,4,66,6
```

File2

```
f,25,4,5,66
g,25,4,55,6
h,25,4,5,56
i,25,41,5,61
j,25,4,51,60
```

File3

```
k,20,40,50,60
l,21,40,51,60
```

Comment: @mozway - dupe not match.

Comment: @jezrael are dozens of dupes for this, pick one

Comment: @mozway - So why not close correct dupe? If dozens of them. Not understand.

Comment: Because I think it's close enough. If you prefer choose one of yours (you have many dupes of that). This way you'll get your 15points and a nice link to one of your other dupe which is what you love.

Comment: @mozway - I think closing dupe is great idea. But if close because something similar, dont care about it, only closing, I think it is not corect way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If default `RangeIndex` you can loop in `groupby` with integer division by number of groups:

```
input_file = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

N = 5
for name, g in input_file.groupby(input_file.index // N): 
    g.to_csv(f'file_{name}.csv', ignore_index=True, header=False)
```

---

```
N = 5
for name, g in input_file.groupby(np.arange(len(input_file)) // N): 
    g.to_csv(f'file_{name}.csv', ignore_index=True, header=False)
```

EDIT: If need really write line by line use:

```
N = 5
for name, g in input_file.groupby(input_file.index // N): 
    with open(f'File{name+1}.xml', 'w') as out_file:
        for data in g.to_numpy():
            out_file.write(','.join(str(x) for x in data))
            out_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: Hi in last option you are looping g and what if I want to read based on key example
data["name"]
data["age"]

could you help me how to achieve

Comment: @DhananjayaDN - Then change `input_file.groupby(input_file.index // N)` to `input_file.groupby(['name','age'])`